# Error comparando valores en Android (if)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo la siguiente Activity la cual inicia un servicio de tipo service en android para ello dentro de mi clase Activity tengo lo siguiente

```
Intent i_service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        i_service.putExtra("nombre_clase", "Mapas");
        startService(i_service);
```

y en mi clase MyService.class tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(var,"servicio stratcomand");
        String nombre_clase = intent.getStringExtra("nombre_clase");
        Log.d("bbbbbbbbbb", "valor: "+nombre_clase);
        if(nombre_clase == "Mapas"){
            Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaa", "valor: "+nombre_clase);
        }else{
            Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaa", "noo error ");
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Antes de ingresar a la condicion imprimo la variable nombre_clase el cual no presenta ningun error, pero cuando quiero que me imprima el valor de la misma variable dentro de la condición siempre me sale el mensaje "no error", ya que el valor "Mapas" si existe.

Lo que deseo saber es como hago para resolver este problema, de antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema radica en que no estas comparando objetos de tipo `String` de forma correcta.

Debes usar el método `equals`, de otro modo lo que estas comparando son objetos y no su contenido y, por tanto, siempre van a ser distintos.

Este sería el código correcto:

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(var,"servicio stratcomand");
        String nombre_clase = intent.getStringExtra("nombre_clase");
        Log.d("bbbbbbbbbb", "valor: "+nombre_clase);
        if("Mapas".equals(nombre_clase)){
            Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaa", "valor: "+nombre_clase);
        }else{
            Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaa", "noo error ");
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

He puesto `"Mapas".equals(nombre_clase)` en vez de `nombre_clase.equals("Mapas")` para evitar posibles `NullPointerException` ya que no compruebas explicitamente si el valor es nulo.

Answer (score 0):

> En el lenguaje `Java` se útiliza la función `equals()` para comparar
>   `Strings`, NUNCA debería usarse el operador `==` .

```
   // if(nombre_clase == "Mapas"){
    if(nombre_clase.equals("Mapas")){
        Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaa", "valor: "+nombre_clase);
    }else{
        Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaa", "noo error ");
    }
```

---

También podrías usar [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), que realiza una comparación no importando mayúsculas o minúsculas, por ejemplo:

Si `nombre_clase` tiene el valor de "mapas":

```
nombre_clase = "mapas"
```

Esta comparación tendría un valor `false`:

```
nombre_clase.equals("Mapas")
```

en cambio si usas `equalsIgnoreCase()`, tendría un valor `true`:

```
nombre_clase.equalsIgnoreCase("Mapas")
```