# Como leer archivos mp3 de la memoria?

Tags: android, android-studio

como leo los archivos mp3 de la memoria ? se reproducir los archivos de la carpeta raw, pero no se como leer los que tenga el usuario en su android...

Tengo creada estas variables

```
    Context context = this;
    ListView lista;
    ArrayList<Object> elementos = new ArrayList<>();
```

En el Oncreate tengo lo siguiente

```
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_musica);
    cargardatos();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, elementos);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

y fuera del OnCreate tengo la clase cargardatos

```
private void cargardatos() {
    elementos.add("primero");
    elementos.add("segundo");
    elementos.add("tercero");

}
```

al iniciar la aplicación muestra lo siguiente
[image: Esto muestra en el telefono o emulador]

Quiero que en la parte que dice primero, segundo y etc, se coloque la musica que tiene el usuario en su telefono, los botones para reproducir los creare luego.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Si agregas la clase en la que vas a reproducir el audio, que contenga el botón play, stop... seria mucho mas fácil darte una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @Israel ya edite la pregunta y agrege la clase que tengo, gracias

Comment: Como no tienes mucho construido, he respondido a tu pregunta principal de como cargar un archivo de música almacenado en el dispositivo.

Comment: gracias @Israel y no tengo mucho contruido por que apenas voy iniciando la app y pienso hacer algo como un reproductor con varias opciones de personalizacion que quiero agregarle, pero nunca habia trabajado con el media player desde archivos fuera de la app (fuera de la carpeta raw), mil gracias en un momento miro bien tu codigo y que le puedo adicionar, mil gracias, ya tenia parte del getExternalstorage pero no sabia sobre como acceder a la musica, gracias

Comment: Estamos para ayudar, cualquier duda que se te presente, no dudes en consultar.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado creo que lo mismo que esta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67600/error-comparando-valores-en-android-if/67602#67602] se esta trabajando en android studio

Comment: @LeonardoHenao Que estés usando "android-studio" no significa que el problema sea de "android-studio", este problema es de "android" independientemente de la plataforma de desarrollo usada. Según tu razonamiento deberías poner etiquetas con el emulador usado, sistema operativo, arquitectura, etc...

Comment: @LeonardoHenao Tampoco te vendría mal aprender a usar las tíldes, formatear el texto y saber la diferencia entre clase y método.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar TODAS mis publicaciones y corregirlas, creo que deberías aprender un poco sobre a que se le denomina método y a que clase.

Comment: PASO MI SOLUCIÓN https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206642/compartir-archivos-multimedia-de-la-carpeta-raw-en-las-redes-solucionado

Answer (score 1):

Para leer un archivo de música basta con llamar a `setDataSource(archivo)` de la siguiente manera:

```
String rutaArchivo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/carpeta/musica.mp3";
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(rutaArchivo);
mediaPlayer.prepare();   
mediaPlayer.start()
```